# How can you force predictions of a linear model to start at the same point as new data

Tags: r, lm, predict

I would like my logistic regression model to start at the same point as a predictor variable.

Data:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = c(0:20, 0:20), 
  y = c(log(10:30 + 2), log(10:30 + 10)),
  init = c(rep(log(10 + 2), 21), rep(log(10 + 10), 21)),
  group = c(rep('A', 21), rep('B', 21))
)
```

Model:

```
lm_fit <- lm(y ~ log(x + 1) + init, data = df)
```

Example of model fitted to data:

```
newdata <- df %>%
  filter(group == 'A') %>%
  mutate(pred_y = predict(lm_fit, newdata = newdata, type = 'response')) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(y, pred_y), names_to = 'pred_type', values_to = 'value')
    ggplot(aes(x, value, colour = pred_type)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

How can I change my model so the red line (model) starts at the same value as the blue line (data)? i.e. when `x=0`, `pred_y = y`.

[image]

Comment: This is really a data modeling question rather than a specific programming question. It's probably better to get modeling advice from [stats.se] first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `init` variable, you have to treat it as an offset (its coefficient will be 1) and disable the intercept (`-1` in model formula).

```r
lm_fit <- lm(y ~ log(x + 1) + offset(init) - 1, data = df)
```

[image: plot]

After changing the model formula to `log(y) ~ log(x + 1)` a possible approach is to transform the `y` variable and use its new value in *x* = 0 for the offset (`init`) variable (I would actually recommend to always derive the offset from the *y* variable and not compute it independently). This way only the data is modified and the rest will remain the same.

```r
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(y = log(y),
         init = y[x==0])
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you. If the model formula changed to `lm(log(y) ~ log(x +1)`, how would this change your solution?